# Logic error on counting consonants in a string C++

Tags: c++

So Im trying to count count vowels, consonants and special character. I got the vowels and special part to work, but not the consonants. Here's the code;

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void characterType(string);

int main()
{
    string input = "Testing a sentence.";
    characterType(input);
}

void characterType(string input)
{
    int vowel, consonant, special = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
    {
        char character = input[i];
        
        if((character >= 'a' && character <= 'z') ||(character >= 'A' && character <= 'Z'))
        {
            character = tolower(character);
            
            if (character == 'a' || character == 'e' || character == 'i' || character == 'o' || character == 'u')
            {
                vowel++;
            }
            else
            {
                consonant++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            special++;
        }
    }
    cout<< "Vowels: " << vowel << endl;
    cout<< "Consonant: " << consonant << endl;
    cout<< "Special Character: " << special << endl;
}
```

Here's the output;
[image]

I cant seem to figures it out, does anyone have any idea?

Comment: You doesnt initialize vowel and consonant.

Comment: Please don't use conditions such as `(character >= 'a' && character <= 'z') ||(character >= 'A' && character <= 'Z')` That's not portable. Use [`std::isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) and other [character classification](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte#Character_classification) functions instead.

Comment: Just to emphasize,  your comparison of `A-Z, a-z` will fail if the characters are non-English (your code will falsely claim that a good non-English letter is a "special character"), or if the collating sequence is not ASCII, but instead something like EBCDIC, where the letters are not contiguous.  That's the reason why you should be using `std::isalpha` -- the system knows better than the programmer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definitions

```
int vowel, consonant, special = 0;
```

only initialized `special` to `0`. The other two variables are uninitialized and will have *indeterminate* values.

You need to explicitly initialize all variables you want to have a specific initial value:

```
int vowel = 0, consonant = 0, special = 0;
```

This is why many recommend to only define one variable per statement:

```
int vowel = 0;
int consonant = 0;
int special = 0;
```